# Android Oreo prevent installing directly from source

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have implemented app update which sideload apk from my server. It will download and popup for install after download completed.
On Oreo, it just stop after download.
After some digging, I also found that the apk also can't be installed directly from Google Drive.
Both apks are fine if I download it first to local storage, and installed successfully.
I have read many suggestion to enable 'unknown source' to drive and the result still the same.

Comment: For security purpose you can't install apk directly by downloading you atleast have to enable Unknown Sources, it was not only oreo but before than oreo may be jellybean.

Comment: i knew that. for oreo they have changed it to individual setting. but it still not allowing me to install the apk. it there anothe workaround in oreo?